Infinite Regression of Matter
I have had some thoughts around the nature of matter and fundamental particles and it goes as such. The consequences of my line of reasoning I feel would be significant if correct. Help me understand if there are any flaws in this.

If something is material, it takes up space and has a structure.
What we call a fundamental particle in the realm of physics or chemistry must still therefore have a structure or take up space.

This disqualifies them from being the end of the regression of composition of matter. Otherwise any potential fundamental particle would take up space without having a structure which takes up space. That seems logically impossible.
If a particle is made of other structures, those structures would disqualify the particle from being the true fundamental particle. Is it not implied that because we logically can infinitely subdivide matter like we can subdivide infinitely between any two numbers in mathematics or any two points in space that an infinite regression occurs? Whether or not we can reproduce it in a laboratory/particle accelerator is irrelevant logically to this line of reasoning.

If the above is true, there exists an actualized infinity within every atom.
Because actualized infinities are logically impossible, therefore, there must be an immaterial end to the regression of the composition of matter. Fundamental particles as they exist cannot be that end.

Is this line of reasoning discussed in the literature?

Thanks for the feedback! I'll take a look at all the responses here (Vasubandhu and Kant so far)

This seems to overlook the possibility that matter has an internal structure about which we know nothing.

But as for "actualized infinity": I think that for any point of an atom that is not dead center, there is a point in the same direction but half as close. But: The claim that it doesn't matter whether this is merely theoretical ... depends on what matters to you. Do the physicists have a consensus about whether the actual 3-dimensional space we seem to live in "is" identical to euclidean 3-space, in the limit as size —> 0 ???  I don't know.

I am not familiar with the literature, but there are some errors in your thesis, as follows:
Some subatomic particles are known to be composite objects with internal constituents. These particles have a finite, measurable size and present themselves as tiny spheres. Those internal constituents however present themselves not as tiny spheres but as dimensionless points with measurable attributes but zero volume, which are trapped inside that spherical volume.
Other subatomic particles present themselves directly as dimensionless points with measurable attributes (including mass and charge) but zero volume and are not confined within spherical volumes.

I find it more plausible we define particles as having zero dimensions due to the difficulty of measurement, not a physical reality. Every previous fundamental particle: atom, proton, neutron, or electron has been proved not so. In the past few hundred years we have already jumped orders of magnitude down the ladder of matter composition. Defining something as dimensionless and having zero volume is the exact logical impossibility I'm getting at. That's defining away the problem because of physical limitations of measurement. It's easier to believe influence of dark matter than volumeless mass

@Vehrn, you are wrong. Electrons have no internal structure. Philosophers can point out as many logical impossibilities in the world of physics as they wish but the universe is under no obligation to react in any way. You however are free to believe whatever is easiest for you. Physicists do not have that luxury.

@nielsnielsen although physicists might have the luxury of calling things totally unlike tiny rocks something other than a word that means "tiny rock" and saving students and educators a lot of trouble.

In the past few hundred years we went from no fundamental building blocks of matter to one, to 3, to dozens, including fermions, bosons, neutrinos, and many more. "A smallest occuring repeatedly observed and recognizable structure with some understood behaviors" is a far cry from reaching the bottom of the composition of matter. I hope you can see that @nielsnielsen. In fact, even electrons are made of quarks which is accepted science.

@Vehrn, OK: which type of quarks make up an electron? Name their charges, spins, color, and whether they are anti or not.

Electrons (and other leptons) are not dimensionless. Bound electron, for example, occupy its orbit (of a well-defined spatial radius); free electrons, technically speaking, spread across the entire space. However, they do not have an internal structure, they are not composite, and are truly elementary.

This is a fallacy of definition by mutual exclusivity. Fundamental particles are not Vehrn-material, since they have no internal structure and have no spatial extent. They are particle-physics-material, since they have nonzero mass. Making up a definition for a word is fine. Insisting that the things that go with other definitions of the same word must have the properties defined in your definition is nonsense.
Batman is a masked superhero.
Captain Smith had a batman who attended to his equipment in 1835. Therefore Captain Smith must have been attended by a masked superhero.

I feel this is just defining away the problem. With a sufficiently powerful, sufficiently precise particle accelerator or microscope, you're making the case that there is nothing to see when viewing a particle that has a measurable mass. I find that incoherent.

@vehrn "how do we know that dimensionless particles are dimensionless (and what does that mean in terms of actual measurements)" would be a good question for physics se (although "all physicists are wrong, prove me wrong" is not).

If it's not a duplicate and you do ask and don't get an answer in a day or two, feel free to tag me and I'll be happy to answer it there.

That's probably the way I'll go. I am more concerned with understanding how something can be shown to be a volume-less mass. Explanations I've heard tend to be along the lines of "This isn't a problem because we have defined it as not a problem." A smallest repeatedly observed particle and its behavior is a far cry from 'it has been proved no amount of technology can ever reveal any constituents of this form of material for these reason(s).' I'm guess the science isn't there, because every time someone has made that case before their theories were wrong. Maybe I'll be pleasantly surprised.

IMO the whole discussion about infinite divisibility or non-divisibility of elementary particles leads astray. The assumptions of the OP's post are not realistic:
We learn from physics: To split “elementary particles” into components needs to  fire at them with high energy. The high energy contributes to transform the particles into new particles according to the formula E=m*c^2 (Energy E equals mass m times the speed of light c squared).
As a consequence, we do not get separate components of the original particle. Instead we get new particles, created from the mass of the original particle and the energy of the impact.
Added: I want to emphasize the need to accommodate ourself to the Einstein equivalence of mass and energy. One cannot focus on one of the two in separation from the other.

You're right, I am not really concerned if something is physically divisible to justify whether or not it exists with a structure. If it is physically observable given sufficiently advanced technology is what I am concerned with in my "argument" here. Us finding the minimal organized level of how matter behaves reproducibly is a far cry from the issue I am trying to highlight here.
